# java sql server jdbc connection string comma in server name

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

I'm trying to connect to a SQL Server DB with JDBC in java. 
This is my connection String:

```
"jdbc:sqlserver://XYZ\\SQLEXPRESS,3000;user=xxxxxx;password=xxxxx;databaseName=dbname;"
```

The server name is XYZ\SQLEXPRESS,3000. I escaped the \ character but im still getting the following error

```
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The connection to the host XYZ, named instance SQLEXPRESS,3000 failed.
```

Comment: it seams that the URL is not correct, what version of sqlserver you are using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [URL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms378428(v=sql.110).aspx) should look like this :

```
jdbc:sqlserver://[serverName[\instanceName][:portNumber]][;property=value[;property=value]]
```

In your case :

```
"jdbc:sqlserver://XYZ\\SQLEXPRESS:3000;user=xxxxxx;password=xxxxx;databaseName=dbname;"
//-------------------------------^
```

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, if it were me, I would make a new instance, sans commas. This seems like it will be a nightmare for you going forward.

edit: Apparently we're looking for a port number, not a comma in a SQL instance...